# Can I process my response right before I send it to the client in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel-4

I want to parse and do changes to the HTML I want to send to the client, right before it's sent.

I figured out I could use the `App::after` filter, which exposes both the `response` and `request` objects to me but then I got stuck...

I want to somehow get the HTML from the response, parse it, change it and send the changed HTML to the client instead but cannot find any properties/methods I can use in the `response` object.

Calling `dd($response)` crashes my browser and cannot find anything related in the `Laravel` website...

Does anyone know how/if what I want to do is possible?

Comment: After filters are to do something after a response has been sent. It will be easier if you do the following. You can render the HTML with the `render()` method on your view. And use a helper function to change it. This helper function could be places within your BaseController, which would then be accessible to all controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was use the `getContent` and `setContent` methods of the `$response` object.

So my filter now looks something like this:

```
App::after(function($request, $response){
    $html = $response->getContent();
    $html = Helpers::transformHtml($html);

    $response->setContent($html);
});
```